# Guava: Iterables transform method usage

Tags: java, guava

I have tree classes `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`. `ClassA` and `ClassB extends ClassC`. I have merged `Multimap<ClassC`> and I have `Collection` of objects of different types. I wold like to get this objects from `Collection` but how to distinguish this objects? I have created `Collection<? super ClassC> coll = multimap.get(key)` and I wold like to get this objects using `trnasform` method but I don't know how to distinguish object's type. Can you give me advice? I appreciate every help.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinguish"? What are you trying to achieve / what is your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the sound of it you actually need to filter the collection down to the types you want:

```
Collection<? super ClassC> coll = multimap.get(key);

Iterable<ClassA> classAs = Iterables.filter(coll, ClassA.class);
Iterable<ClassB> classBs = Iterables.filter(coll, ClassB.class);
```

Update from @EtienneNeveu using the overload `Iterables.filter(Iterable<?> unfiltered, Class<T> type)` removes any type issues with my original answer.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was really helpful for me :)

Comment: I think you want to use the overload `Iterables.filter(Iterable<?> unfiltered, Class<T> type)`. That way, the returned iterable has the right generic type. Javadoc: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html